# How do you add security group ID to other security group in CDK?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

```js
const securityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, "Ec2SecurityGroup", {
    vpc,
});

const securityGroupId = "sg-test";

securityGroup.addIngressRule(
    // doesn't work
    ec2.Peer.ipv4(securityGroupId),
    // doesn't work
    ec2.Peer.prefixList(securityGroupId),
    ec2.Port.tcp(5432),
    "SecurityGroup of Test"
);
```

I want to add an ID of security group but it seems like it's impossible...

Comment: " // doesn't work" - is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by looking at the documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.SecurityGroup.html

As yoou can see, you can pass a `SecurityGroup` to the `peer` attribute.

To create a `SecurityGroup` from its ID, use `SecurityGroup.fromSecurityGroupId`:

```js
const securityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, "Ec2SecurityGroup", {
    vpc,
});

const otherSecurityGroup = ec2.SecurityGroup.fromSecurityGroupId(
    this,
    "OtherSecurityGroup",
    "sg-test"
);

securityGroup.addIngressRule(
    otherSecurityGroup,
    ec2.Port.tcp(5432),
    "SecurityGroup of Test"
);
```